# How to pass jquery ajax response to bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-4

I currently have this that displays response in an alert box but want it displayed in a bootstrap modal but have not got it to work yet. This is my jquery code.
I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  $("#set").click(function(){
    $('.spinner-grow').show();
    var id =  $('.auth').val();

  $.post("https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle",
  {
    id: id,
    secret_key: "FLWS****************20628-X"
  },

  function(status){
    $('.modal-body').html(status);
   $('#verifyModal').modal('show');
    $('.spinner-grow').hide();
  });
});


</script>
```

I have this as the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="verifyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="verifyModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6>Payment Veification</h6>
      </div>



      <div class="modal-body" align="center">

      </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">

         <button style="outline: none;" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true"><small style="color: navy; font-size: 15px;"><b>Close</b></small></span>
        </button>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How exactly can i make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135110/jquery-ajax-with-es6-promises , have a look at promises

Answer (score 2):

you could have tried something like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "url",
  data:data
  success: function(status) {
    $('.modal-body').html(status);
    $('#verifyModal').modal('show');
    $('.spinner-grow').hide();
  };
});
```