# AJAX function inside forEach Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a function that does a foreach loop in a list of views and needs to send an AJAX request for each view in the loop. When it gets the results in the success function, it checked if a specific Id is returned and, if it is, adds this view to a selectBox. The problem is that when I tried to define the .change event on the selectBox it gave me an error as no option have been added. I have thought about adding ajaxStop, but I have other different AJAX request.
Does anybody knows how could i wait till those Ajax request have been finished, but no others?

```
 var newdiv = $('<div id="viewListDiv" style ="margin:auto" ></div> ')
    var selectBox = $('<select id = "ViewsList" class="form-control" style="width:250px;margin-left: 70px; margin-rigth:70px;" ></select>');
views.forEach(function (view)
    {
        _this.continue = true;
        var guid = view.search({ "type": "resource" })[0].data.guid;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "api/forge/modelderivative/metadata/model",
            data: {
                "urn": urn,
                "viewableId": guid,
            },
                success: function (metadata) {
                    _this.getIds(metadata.data);
                    if (_this.listdbId.includes(dbId[0])) {
                        var newOpt = new Option(view.data.viewableID, view.data.name);
                        selectBox.append(newOpt);
                    }
                    _this.listdbId = []
                }
        });
    });
        selectBox = selectBox[0];
        selectBox.change(function (opt) {
            //launch change function
    });
```

Comment: You'd have a much easier time using an API that returns a Promise, like `fetch` or the `axios` library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery select change not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194177/jquery-select-change-not-firing)

Comment: @thedude `jQuery.ajax` does return a promise

Comment: @Liam Their docs say it returns a `jqXHR` object which is a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object

Comment: [JQuery 3 implemented the A+ promise standard I believe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23958233/542251). It looks like no one keeps the jQuery docs up to date anymore which isn't really surprising given it's age.

Comment: JQuery 3 seems to be a mere 5 years old, so cutting edge...for jQuery standards

Answer (score 0):

It looks most like a pure Javascript question rather than Autodesk Forge Viewer. Anyways, no matter you choose to use `fetch` or `jquery.ajax`, the AJAX call is an async job. We need to take advantage of the Promise to ensure the call is finished. Here is a revision of your code snippt:

```js
const getModel = (view) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let guid = view.search({ "type": "resource" })[0].data.guid;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "api/forge/modelderivative/metadata/model",
            data: {
                "urn": urn,
                "viewableId": guid,
            },
            success: function (metadata) {
                resolve(metadata);
            }
        }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus) => reject(jqXHR, textStatus));
    });
};

const tasks = views.map((view) => getModel(view));
const results = await Promise.all(tasks);

for(let i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
    let metadata = results[i];

    //..
}
```